# What Meteor event handler should I use for onchange form submits

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an html form that I would like to submit without having a submit button. What event listener should I be using? thanks!

editProfile.html

```
<form class="edit-profile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload Profile Image: 
    <Input type="file" name="profileImage" id="profileImage" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <br>

</form>
```

editProfile.js

```
    Template.editProfile.events({
        "change .edit-profile": function(event){
            console.log("works");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work with `submit form` or by using its class, like:

```
Template.editProfile.events({
  "submit .edit-profile": function(event){
    console.log("works");
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm... I tried that first but it didn't work, it seems like the submit event doesn't get triggered.

Comment: My answer is based on you mentioning a form submit listener in your question, try and hit the return key after you select your file. Looking at your example I think you should rather do `change #profileImage`

Answer (score 0):

After much research I solved it by still having a button but hiding it and triggering through onchange

editProfile.html

```
<form class="edit-profile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 Upload Profile Image: 
 <Input type="file" name="profileImage" id="profileImage" onchange="document.getElementById('theSubmitButton').click();">
 <br>
 <input type="submit" id="theSubmitButton" style="display: none;" value="Upload file">
</form>
```

editProfile.js

```
Template.editProfile.events({
  "submit .edit-profile": function(event){
    console.log("works");
  }
});
```